# Exclude routes with file extension from Express routes

Tags: angularjs, regex, node.js, express

I'd like AngularJs to deal with most of my routes so I don't need to specify routes in Express AND Angular at the same time. So I created a "catch all" route like this:

```
app.use('/api', api); // server-side stuff
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //static files
app.get('*', function (req, res) { //angular stuff
    res.render('index');
});
```

Then on my Angular app, if the route doesn't exist, I handle it this way

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    templateUrl: '/partials/404.html', 
    controller: 'DummyCtrl'
});
```

The problem is that, if the `static()` route does not match a file in the public directory, it will then go to the next "catch all" route.

This cause some issues as the server returns `res.render('index');` (the whole page) which then is injected in the page by AngularJs so I get a warning `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`.

I'd like to re-write my "catch all" route to only match routes if they don't match files.

I believe what I need is a regex for the Angular route that would exclude routes if they look like files. Eg: exclude "*.html," "*.png", etc.

Comment: `^.*\.(?!(?:png|html)$).*$`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: `/\/[^.]*$|^(?:https?:)?\/\/[^\/]+$/`

Comment: where it is asking about finding `http`?

Comment: Nowhere. I added that so that it recognizes raw domain names (e.g. 'http://www.nationstates.net' by itself) as 'not like files'.